# MVC Using Domain Models in View Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is the following OK to do? I know Domain Models should never be used in views but is it ok to use Domain Models in your View Models? For some very small models it doesn't seem worth it to be creating and managing a View Model for them.

For Example

```
public class LoginDomainModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public long UserTypeID { get; set; }      
    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; } 
}
public class UserTypeDomainModel
{
    public UserType()
    {
        this.Logins = new List<Login>();
    }
    public long UserTypeID { get; set; }
    public string UserType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Login> Logins { get; set; }
}

public class LoginViewModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public long UserTypeID {get; set;}

    //Right here
    public List<UserTypeDomainModel> UserTypesSelectList {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally I use domain models in the view *if they would naturally be an exact fit*.  That is likely to happen only on trivial projects that are CRUD in nature (editing the domain entities in a straightforward way).  I find it a waste of time to create an exact copy of a domain entity for the sake of purity.

I will *never* modify a domain model in the slightest to account for needs of the view.  In 95%+ of my projects, this is the circumstance I find myself in.  The moment you pollute the domain for the sake of the view, you introduce maintainability headaches.

Comment: Until your domain entities update and your view hasn't yet. Then you get headaches with new required fields that aren't presented in the interface. To each his/her own I guess, it just depends on how often changes in your domain model can or do occur.

Comment: @BradChristie: In 95% of projects I have separate a view model and domain model with a mapping layer (automapper is good).  For 5% of projects (small, simple ones... often 1 person ones) that is overkill.

Comment: There are possibly security implications. I find that using domain model entities in the view/viewmodel significantly increases the likelihood that you will introduce security vulnerabilities in the form of "overposting" attacks(see also http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx). I also observe that using domain entities directly in view/viewmodel is often a sign of the "anemic domain model" anti-pattern (http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html). I will use "value objects" in the view/viewmodel, but not entities.

Comment: The security issue remains if you use something like Automapper without the same due care as shown in Scott's blog post (excluding certain mappings).  In a trivial case (the only one where I consider having no separate domain model), the domain model is going to be anemic no matter what because by definition the subject matter is trivial.  Any time there is any richness to the domain, I would have separate domain and view models for this very reason.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled for a long time with the perceived duplication caused by separate view models and domain models. I would assert that since they are intended for different purposes it's not *really* duplication, but it still feels "wrong" to declare so many similar properties.

In very small projects (especially ones with a highly trusted group of authenticated users) I may just bind directly to the domain models and be done with it. Or I may mix and match if the view model requires a different structure (as @Eric J. describes).

**However**: The ModelBinder will attempt to match values in the request to properties on your model. This means that any property on your domain model can potentially be populated by a (rogue) request. There are ways to prevent this, but for me the peace of mind outweighs a little extra effort creating separate view models.

I don't see an absolute need to create a separate view model for readonly, unbound values (possibly the list of user types in your case, though `public virtual ICollection<Login> Logins` may negate this).

Alternatively, you may wish to project the domain model to a UI-oriented abstraction (e.g. `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`). You can use `SelectListItems` for a variety of input mechanisms, so you aren't tying yourself to a particular UI behavior.

Even with abstraction, you may still need to validate that the request doesn't contain an illegal value. For example, perhaps only super admins can assign certain `UserTypeDomainModel` IDs. Regardless of abstraction, you still need to validate this.

**TLDR:** abstract domain models as much as is practical, find appropriate abstractions (a new view model isn't always the correct answer), and be (slightly paranoid) about input validation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "Domain model".   Do you mean EF entities?  Or do you mean business layer objects?

It's never a good idea to pass EF entities to the view, particularly if you're using default model binding.  This can create security issues if you are not careful.  Although the same issues can occur if you're not careful with business objects passed to the view.

One of the huge advantages of view models is that you have much finer control over mapping of data, so you can validate more easily that only the correct maps occur.

It all comes down to your app though.  If it's a simple app, then it may not be worth the trouble of doing more complex mappings.  If it's a complex app, that must live for a long time, and will likely to be updated a lot.. then you should definitely invest the effort.

Comment: I was referring to EF Entities.

Comment: @Preston - then that's your data model, not your domain model.  And my advice above still applies