# Building a single page application - is MVC the right tool?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, prototypejs

Based on the answer to another question:

[How to DTOs fit into the Repository+Service Pattern of MVC Applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126899/how-to-dtos-fit-into-the-repositoryservice-pattern-of-mvc-applications)

What benefits does MVC provide for a single-page application?  When does it become better to use a WebAPI / prototype stack as opposed to ASP .NET MVC?

Comment: Have you read http://www.asp.net/single-page-application?

Comment: The pro/cons of using mvc vs "any other approach" is the same for 1, 10 or N pages. So you should look for a general comparison, not "1 page specific" comparison.