# Change name the For helper methods create

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making a form with MVC and am using the `[ControlType]For([expression])` helper methods (EG `Html.TextBoxFor(...)`)

To bind the data to the controls I am using the following ViewModel:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    //The Model that will be used to bind data to the elements
    public UserModel User { get; set; }

    //Used to bind selectable options to DropDownLists
    public SelectList DescentTypes { get; set; }
    public SelectList GenderTypes { get; set; }
}
```

When using this the name of the controls get set to `name="Property.SubProperty"` (EG `name="User.Id"`) but I would rather it show as `name="Id"` on my html form.

Is it possible to do this without having to write a lot of custom code so the framework can translate it back to the ViewModel (UserViewModel) or just the Model (User) itself?

Comment: May I ask why it's an issue for you that it's named `User.Id`? It's named like that because of possible collisions.

Comment: I think that would require you to write a custom model binder. That being said, I think it would be actually *easier* to use flat view-models and map the properties to them from models via any kind of mapping library...

Comment: @neoistheone It feels "dirty" form a html naming conventions perspective. I assumed the name was there for reflection purposes when re-hydrating the object.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek This posted viewmodel will have more objects added to it that are related to it. So there will be a User, Roles, etc... (a master summary for a single entity)

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise leaving the default naming in place unless you have a very good reason to alter it. IDs (which it appears your question is leaning towards) are more flexible.

### Changing IDs

IDs aren't submitted with a form, so you can set them as desired without breaking model binding. By default, they are hierarchical, but you can override them inline:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor( o => o.UserName, new { id = "foo" } )
```

Of course, this is manual work.

If the big concern is external JS/CSS, I'd suggest using class names and `data-*` attributes in your (CSS/jQuery/whatever) selectors rather than IDs.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor( o => o.User.UserName, new { data_role="grand-total" } )
```

It's still manual, but it's descriptive and independent of an ID.

Sometimes I use a snippet of script in my views to initialize a larger JS class with data that is most easily available directly within the view. This lets the bulk of the script reside in an external file while allowing dynamic values to be used to initialize it. This is useful for more than just IDs.

### Altering Generated Markup and Binding

For reference, let's say you wanted to change ID *and* name.

1. Write your own `HtmlHelper` extension methods to create the markup you want. You could probably wrap the existing methods that do not take an expression and pass explicit values to them to indicate the name that you want.
2. Write your own `ModelBinder` to map the raw form collection.
3. Determine a strategy for dealing with hierarchical objects (which is the main reason the naming convention exists in the first place).

Item #3 could be addressed by decorating properties to indicate how the naming should be performed and how model binding should map. This could become complicated quickly.

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    // use this metadata to determine how to handle properties on this member
    [Flatten]
    public UserModel User { get; set; }

    public SelectList DescentTypes { get; set; }
    public SelectList GenderTypes { get; set; }
}
```

### Alternatives

1. Flatten your view model by adding `User`'s properties directly to it. It looks like your are composing your view model from domain model(s). This isn't usually a good idea. I'd suggest [reading the pros/cons of binding directly to domain models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045445/mvc-using-domain-models-in-view-models).
2. Leave the naming alone. It really isn't hurting anything and it makes life easy. You can avoid ever directly working with names/IDs in your client code by using helper methods.

For example:

```
// JavaScript + Razor
var name = "@Html.NameFor( o => o.User.Id )";
alert(name);
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful post.  The `User` is more like a DTO as it has only the needed properties to flesh out the view.  How does the javascript and css work if I want to use the Id or name for styles for some reason?  I see you js example but does MVC compile that even if the js file is in an external file?

Comment: 1) makes sense on the `User` type. 2) I reread your question, and it sounds like you are more concerned with IDs than names, so I updated my answer. 3) I added a bit of info on dealing with external files.